# PHP: `move_uploaded_file` isn't properly accessing `tmp_name` of user submited file

Tags: php, forms, file, upload

I've been struggling for the past couple days to submit an image through a form and have my php script save it in the designated directory. I've tried using `$.ajax`, I've tried using `XMLHttpRequest`, and now I've just copied a simpler script from [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp) and tweaked it.

`move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)` evaluates to `false`and I don't believe any warnings are given, so according to the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php), there was a problem accessing the file.

The script response is

```
/private/var/tmp/phpwwBaBr
Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.
```

Also, the error code from `echo $_FILE['fileToUpload']['error'];` is `0`, which means the upload is successful, yet still no file in `../includes/galleryImages/`.

---

Here's the code:

```
<form action="archive_upload.php" id='file_form' method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset='UTF-8'>
     Select image to upload:
     <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
     <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

---

```
<?php
    $target_dir = "../includes/galleryImages/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
    $uploadOk = 1;
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
        if($check !== false) {
            $uploadOk = 1;
        } else {
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }
    }

    echo $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"].'<br>';    

    /* This is the line that returns false */
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"] ). " has been uploaded.<br>";

    } else {
        echo "Error uploading file.<br>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Make sure you have error reporting enabled in the script. Check your PHP error log on the server for the warnings.

Comment: The problem may be that you don't have write permission to the target directory.

Comment: @Barmar oops, I executed `sudo chmod u+rwx /private/var/tmp` & `sudo chmod -R 755 /private/var/tmp` and now I'm getting error code 6...missing tmp folder!

Comment: It should be `sudo chmod a=rwxt /private/var/tmp`

Comment: But the original problem was probably with the **target** directory, not the temp directory.

Comment: @Barmar ok, so these are the warnings given:

Warning: move_uploaded_file(../includes/galleryImages/pic.png): failed to open stream: Permission denied in ~/Sites/proj1/htdocs/archive_upload.php on line 38

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/private/var/tmp/phpmsy8n5' to '../includes/galleryImages/pic.png' in ~/Sites/proj1/htdocs/archive_upload.php on line 38

Comment: If you are getting permission denied error, then you need to give your folders read and write permission, so you can successfully upload the file. Why don't you just try to upload in the current dir and see what happens.

Comment: also, if you are in a hurry to get something done, [try this script](https://github.com/samayo/bulletproof)

Comment: Use an absolute path from the current file/directory: `__DIR__ . '/../includes..'`. It's hard to be sure where relative paths will end up and `/galleryImages` is certainly not what you want.

Comment: @sam_io Ok, so it works if I use the current directory! Still no luck with the relative path I was using originally. I guess I should just move the folder there since users shouldn't be uploading to the includes file anyway?

Comment: No, first try @deceze answer, probably like `__DIR__ . '/../includes/galleryImages/'` also, when you give read+write permission to your directories, it is better to use the `-R` flag so, the directive applies to all sub folders, otherwise, you will encounter some permission related errors.